# How to display the tables in a tablespace on DB2

Tags: db2

I need to get a list of tables for each tablespace. I listed the tablespaces and their containers, but I can't find a way to display which tables are related to each tablespace, I am only interested in 4 tablespaces, so I could do one at a time.  Is there a query that I can run in db2 8.1?

Comment: You should probably mention your database platform. In DB2 for LUW `SYSCAT.TABLES` has columns `TBSPACE` and `TBSPACEID`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I used syscat.tables to get a tablespace for a single table: SELECT * FROM syscat.tables WHERE tabname like table1. With this I get everything for that table including the tablespace related to it.  But if I tried to reverse it: SELECT tabname FROM syscat.tables WHERE tblspace like tablespaceA  I get zero output.

Comment: @PBJu - a `LIKE` without a wildcard is the same as `=`, that might be your problem.  Also, does your query take into account casing for the tablespace?  As tokens, SQL is effectively case in-sensitive, but I'm not so sure about the contents of the sysinfo tables.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse - That was the problem.  I used a wildcard in the LIKE statement, and upper case for the tablespace name and it worked. Thanks!